# Inserting script into VueJS components

Tags: vue.js, scripting

I wanted to pull scripts and insert them into VueJS components manually. For example, pulling Bootstrap CDN or other external JS scripts and inserting it manually into VueJS components.
Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you have any sample code?

Comment: No , But u can try creating small component

Comment: please add your snippet in readable format , it is not readable in comment.

Comment: I just did that past few days. For example, 

`export default 
{ name: 'app', 
   created () { 
        let recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script')      recaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') document.head.appendChild(recaptchaScript) 
    } 
} `

Seems like it is not working. Btw, that is Google reCaptcha script.

Answer (score 0):

The following component inserts jQuery librery, for some obscure reasons I'm forced to use eval to execute jQuery, I think is related to babel or vue cli.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="validate">Click me</button>
    <div id="div1">Check Load</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
    }),

    mounted() {
      const myScript = document.createElement('script');
      myScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');

      const div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
      div1.appendChild(myScript);
    },
    methods: {
      validate () {
        eval(`$('#div1').html('jQuery Loaded')`);
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```